# Syncing buckets between two S3 Storage Providers

Tags: amazon-s3, riak-cs

I am currently using RIAK CS as an S3 Provider but I want to change to Scality S3. Therefore, I need to migrate the existing data from RIAK to Scality. Is there a quick an easy way of syncing buckets between the two different storage providers? I have got two docker containers running containing the docker images for the two.

One way of doing it would be to simply download the contents of the buckets to a local folder and then upload to Scality using s3cmd or a similar tool. However, I was hoping there was a direct route between the buckets.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would not be a "direct route between the buckets".

While the Amazon S3 `CopyObject` command can copy objects between different Amazon S3 buckets (even if they are in different regions), it will not work with a non-Amazon endpoint.

Your only hope is if Riak/Scality have somehow built-in connectivity with each other.